# my post-receive, a git hook, with two commands doesn't work

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive, post-receive-email

I have three git repositories:

1. a bare repository on my git server
2. a local repository(A) on my laptop (I develop web pages on this machine.)
3. a local repository(B) on a hosting server (I use it as a http server.)

I set a post-receive, a server side hook, on the bare repository to have the repository(B) pull from the bare and have the git server send a notification email when I commit and push from the repository(A) to the bare repository. The post-receive file I made on the bare repository is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -l MYUSER -i PRIVKEY www.HOSTINGSERVER.com "cd GITDIRECTORY;git pull"
. $(dirname $0)/post-receive-email
```

And I also set environmental variables on the bare repository:

```
git config hooks.mailinglist "MyMailAddress"
git config hooks.announcelist "MyMailAddress"
git config hooks.emailprefix "FooBar"
echo FooBar > description
```

I expected the repository(B) pulled and the git server sent a notification email by post-receive-email when I commit and push to the bare repository but the post-receive didn't work as I hoped. It had the repository(B) pull but didn't have the git server send any email. I didn't see any email error in logs on the git server.

When I commented out the ssh part of the post-receive, I got an email. When I commented out the post-receive-email part, the repository(B) pulled correctly. When both the ssh part and the post-receive-email part are active, the post-receive only have the repository(B) pull and didn't send any email.

I don't know why the post-receive doesn't work as I expect when both the ssh part and the post-receive-email part exist at the same time.

Any hint and comment is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: `ssh -n`.

Background facts:

1. The post-receive hook gets input on its standard input.  Reading stdin, you will get one line per updated reference, in the form described in [the githooks documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).
2. All of the Git hooks that receive input on stdin do so on a pipe.  (I contend that this is a bad idea—that they should receive their input as a file descriptor open on a temporary file—but that's a separate battle.  Even if that were not the case you would still need another trick.)
3. Reading the input available on a pipe consumes that input.  Once it's read, it's gone.

   (This, by the way, is why the `read` built-in in shells is so inefficient: it's *necessary* to read the input one byte at a time, so that only as much as `read` is going to read is consumed.)

With that in mind, consider the `ssh` command, and this excerpt from its [documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> **-n**     Redirects stdin from */dev/null* (actually, prevents reading from stdin).

So, what happens if you run `ssh` *without* `-n`?  It will, of course, read stdin.  But ... how *much* will it read?  Well, strictly speaking, that depends: ssh runs several processes and/or threads, and there is a race if there is a great deal of stdin input and the command run on the remote end executes very quickly, but in general, the amount that ssh reads is *all* of stdin.

Now consult background fact #3, and answer the question: what's left on stdin, when ssh finishes?

Now, think about what your post-receive hook that sends email does.  It must, necessarily, read its stdin to see which references were updated.  What data will it get on its stdin?

If you prevent `ssh` from reading (and thereby consuming) all the input, the post-receive hook will be able to read (and consume, but now it doesn't matter any more) all the input, and therefore function correctly.

Comment: OMG! `ssh -n` resolved my problem! Thanks to your explanation, I also understood the background matters. I wasted about half a day for this problem. Thank you very very much!